# How do I filter data in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have buttons `up` and `down`. By clicking, I need to change the index in the array so that the element goes up or down in the list, depending on the button.Now I receive an index, but I do not understand how to change the index, because then the one before it should lower its index? Can someone suggest how to do this?

```
// Redusers

export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case actionTypes.ADD_EXERCISE:
      return [
        ...state,
        Object.assign({}, action.exercise)
      ];
    case actionTypes.DELETE_EXERCISE:
      return state.filter((data, i) => i !== action.id);
    case actionTypes.FILTER_EXERCISE_UP:
      return state.filter((data, i) => i = action.id + 1); //?????????
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


// Action

export const filterExerciseUp = (id) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.FILTER_EXERCISE_UP,
    id: id
  }
};


// Edit Exercise

class EditExercise extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      exerciseName: '',
      exerciseMeasurement: ''
    };
  }
  handleChangeInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      exerciseName: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleChangeSelect = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      exerciseMeasurement: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  deleteExercise(e, index){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.deleteExercise(index);
  }

  filterExerciseUp(e, index){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.filterExerciseUp(index);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    const ListExerciseItems = this.props.exercises.map((exercise, index) =>
      <GridContainer key={index}>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
      <CustomInput
        ref={(input) => this.getMessageInput = input}
        onChange={this.handleChangeInput}
        labelText="Exercise name"
        id="exercise-name"
        formControlProps={{
          fullWidth: true
        }}
        inputProps={{
          defaultValue: exercise.exerciseName
        }}
      />
    </GridItem>
    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={3}>
      <FormControl style={{width: "100%"}} className={classes.formControl}>
        <div className="materialSelect">
          <CustomSelect
            onChange={this.handleChangeSelect}
            labelText="Measurement"
            id="custom-select"
            formControlProps={{
              fullWidth: true
            }}
            inputProps={{
              defaultValue: exercise.exerciseMeasurement
            }}
          >
            <option value="kg">kilograms</option>
            <option value="min">minutes</option>
            <option value="m">meters</option>
          </CustomSelect>
        </div>
      </FormControl>
    </GridItem>
    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={5}>
      <div className={classes.buttonWrapper}>
        <Button
          variant="fab"
          type="button"
          color="info"
          aria-label="ArrowUpward"
          className={classes.button}
          onClick={(e) => this.filterExerciseUp(e, index)}
        >
          <ArrowUpward />
        </Button>
        <Button variant="fab" color="info" aria-label="ArrowDownward" className={classes.button}>
          <ArrowDownward />
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="fab"
          color="warning"
          aria-label="Cancel"
          className={classes.button}
          onClick={(e) => this.deleteExercise(e, index)}
        >
          <Cancel/>
        </Button>
      </div>
    </GridItem>
    <span style={borderItem}></span>
  </GridContainer>
);
return (
  <div>
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}  >
        <Card>
          <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>


            <CardHeader color="primary">
              <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Edit exercise</h4>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              {ListExerciseItems}
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter>
              <Button color="primary" type="submit"> Update Exercise</Button>
            </CardFooter>
          </form>
        </Card>
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  </div>
   );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    exercises: state.exercises
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    deleteExercise: index => 
 dispatch(exerciseAction.deleteExercise(index)),
     filterExerciseUp: index => 
 dispatch(exerciseAction.filterExerciseUp(index))
  }
 };

 export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) 
 (withStyles(styles)(EditExercise));
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen at reducer with action `FILTER_EXERCISE_UP`?

Comment: Actually I don't think it's a good idea to change index in array.But based on what you need,I think you could change the adjacent items in array whether you up or down.And the splice method in Array could help you do this.

Comment: Also, `i = action.id + 1` is probably a bug. Shouldn't it be `i === action.id + 1`?

Comment: @emi I want to swap 2 objects, the current one, and the one that stands before it. But in this action I only have access to the current

Comment: @digorydoo, and what do I need in this case to transfer to the action, the entire array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the exercise from the array, and then re-add it to the previous position:

```
[...]
case actionTypes.FILTER_EXERCISE_UP:
  var position = -1, 
      exercise = null;
  state.filter((data, i) => {
    if(data.id === action.id) {
      # Get exercise position and data
      position = i;
      exercise = data;
      # Filter out
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });

  // Do some tests and comprovations
  [...]

  // Re-add the exercise one position before
  return state.splice(position-1, 0, exercise);
  [...]
```

Comment: `'i'` is not defined...`return state.splice(i-1, 0, exercise);`

Comment: Use `position` instead of `i`.

Comment: it's not what you need, I need to swap the current object and the previous one

Comment: Fixed `i` by `position`

Comment: @max : when we execute filter, we are removing the element from the list. With `splice` we add it one position before it was. Those both actions do the `I need to swap the current object and the previous one` thing.

Comment: The element is now copied to the position above, but not deleted from the position it was on. And for some reason all elements are removed from `redux store`

Comment: Maybe you need to return a copy of the modified state? Something like `return [...splice(position-1,0,exercise)]`. Otherwise, could you post the resulting `redux store` and the state just before returning it (the result of splice)?